# Can the $message argument of the PHP mail function be used for spam purposes?

Tags: php, email, email-spam

If I'm using the PHP [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to send emails out, is it possible for the function to be used for spam by adding things like `To:`, `Cc:`, etc. to the `$message` argument?

For example, would the following call to the PHP `mail` function also Cc example@email.com?
Thanks.

```
$to = 'abc@aol.com';
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'Testing whether example@email.com gets this email by adding 
            Cc: example@email.com to the body.';

mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: No, the message argument is put into the message body, it's not interpreted as headers.

Comment: I'd first say _"Try it out"_. Does the email body contain "CC:..." or not? I'd imagine that this would just include the email in the message body.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar. If you want to write that as an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thanks. Also, JustCarty, your right, I should just test it out, but I wanted to know if there was possibly something weird that could be "hacked" that I wasn't thinking of. Thanks.